# it crashed my browser or it has crashed my browser

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-simple

Which one is correct? Please let me know. It crashed my browser or it has crashed my browser. Comments are appreciated.

Comment: It's the difference between past simple and present perfect. You could search both those tags on this site for lots of information.

Comment: if i say it crashed my browser... is it correct????

Comment: The use of perfect constructions is entirely dependent on context: are you narrating a past event or reporting a current state? A present perfect reports a present state; a simple past narrates a past event.

Answer (score 0):

> A. It crashed my browser

This is an example of the past simple. It is saying that the thing called "it" caused your browser to crash in the past.

> B. It has crashed my browser

This is an example of the present perfect. In this context, it means that the thing called "it" has crashed your browser usually just before you are saying it:

> B. "Gasp"! The virus has crashed my browser!

This would infer that the action of crashing the browser **just happened**

However this would mean something different:

> A. I was trying to order some umbrellas, but then, the website crashed my browser.

This would infer that the crashing of the browser was in the (far) past. So in conclusion, both are correct, but they have slightly different meanings.